# Why while loop isn't running and I do not know why

Tags: java

Whenever I run the code it just ends regardless of what coinFlip is.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```
public void fight(String person, int theirHP){
    int yourHP = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 30 + 1);
    System.out.println("Your HP: " + yourHP + "\nTheirHP: " + theirHP);
    int coinFlip = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 2 + 1);
    int damage;
    System.out.println(coinFlip);
    if (coinFlip == 1) {
        while (yourHP <= 0 || theirHP <= 0) {
            damage = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3 + 1);
            theirHP -= damage;
            System.out.println("Their HP: " + theirHP + "\nYour HP: " + yourHP);
            damage = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3 + 1);
            yourHP -= damage;
            System.out.println("Their HP: " + theirHP + "\nYour HP: " + yourHP);
        }
    }
    if (coinFlip == 0) {
        while (yourHP <= 0 || theirHP <= 0) {
            damage = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3 + 1);
            yourHP -= damage;
            System.out.println("Their HP: " + theirHP + "\nYour HP: " + yourHP);
            damage = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3 + 1);
            theirHP -= damage;
            System.out.println("Their HP: " + theirHP + "\nYour HP: " + yourHP);
        }
    }
}
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: `yourHP <= 0`  "Hit Points" is normally a positive number.  This will make the while loop run only while HP is negative.  Did you mean something like `yourHP >= 0`?

Comment: Also you used `int coinFlip = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 2 + 1);` which can generate only 1 or 2. But your `if`s are checking if `coinFlip` is either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loops will only be entered when the condition evaluates as `true`. I would assume both `yourHP` *and* `theirHP` start with values greater than `0` so

```
while (yourHP <= 0 || theirHP <= 0)
```

evaluates as `false`. I believe you wanted

```
while (yourHP > 0 && theirHP > 0)
```

To end when either values decrease to `0`.

Also, and not directly to your issue,

```
if (coinFlip == 1)
```

should logically be followed by an `else`. Not another test like `if (coinFlip == 0)`. But both bodies appear to do the same thing, so it isn't clear why you have `coinFlip` in the first place.